# Fetch image from Contentful RichText field thorugh GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I need the **link** and **title** of the image asset on the Contentful post to render on an image tag of the blog post component. Firstly, I'm checking the data I'm getting back from Contentful and it's not returning me the image attributes but rather just an Id reference to it. **How can I get all the image attributes on this graphql query?**[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is currently outdated. It's required to use the **__typename** field to access the "embedded-assets-block". Like so:

GraphQL Query

```
query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
      body {
        raw
        references {
          ... on ContentfulAsset {
            contentful_id
            __typename
            title
            fixed(width: 750) {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Gatsby

```
const options = {
    renderNode: {
      [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
        const {
          fixed: { src },
          title,
        } = node.data.target

        return <img src={src} alt={title} />
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for days, thanks so much! I'd buy you a beer if I could. Super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the metadata of the referenced image you have to also query `references`. Make sure to have a look at [the Contentful/Gatsby Richtext documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#contentful-rich-text).

```
{
  allContentfulBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        bodyRichText {
          raw
          references {
            ... on ContentfulAsset {
              contentful_id
              fixed(width: 1600) {
                width
                height
                src
                srcSet
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your comment. Thanks! However, this didn't really solve my problem because the documentation is outdated. I'll post my solution for further reference.